# How to telescope this sum

Tags: summation

This is a classic telescoping series:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}$

I know (well, my teacher told me) that this one is supposed to behave in a similar way:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{1\times 2\times ...\times (k+1)}$

But I can't find how to change that into a difference like in the first one.

Could someone give me a hint about this?

Comment: In the numerator, write $k = (k+1) - 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see, let me try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to rewrite the numerator as a difference:

$$\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = \frac{(k+1) - 1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{k+1}{(k+1)!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!},$$

and in the last form, the telescoping is recognised with an unarmed eye.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the sum as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1-1}{(k+1)!}$$

it can be divided as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right )$$

which is clearly telescoping.